# Bootstrap 3 input group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Now I'm working with bootstrap 3 input group, but the result is not like expectation.
i want make select [input]-[input text]-[button] in one line.
but in my case button have white space inside like this
[Input Group SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97MsA.jpg).
this is my code:

```html
<div class="card-block bg-white">
        <div class="row">
         <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>performance" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
             <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                 <span class="input-group-btn">
                 <select class="form-control input-sm" name="id_cabang" id="id_cabang">
                          <option>Option 1</option>
                          <option>Option 2</option>
                          <option>Option 3</option>
                    </select>
                    </span>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                     <input id="bulan_kinerja" name="bulan_kinerja" type="text" class="form-control input-sm bln_picker" data-provide="datepicker" placeholder="Datepicker" value="<?php echo $bulan_kinerja; ?>"/>
                    </span>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="kinerja_btn">Submit</button>
                    </span>
                </div> 
             </div> 
             </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I had tried some example in google but some case, if the screen width changes smaller, it turns to new line.

I want the result is full of responsive width and pure using bootstrap 3 class. please help. thanks so much.

Comment: Please include the rest of the elements,  so that we can get how white -space is occurring.

Comment: i updated the code. its maybe i use input-btn-group in every input... so the element is divided with same size.

Comment: Provide the complete code,  which is causing the whitsespace.

Answer (score 3):

You must include the BootStrap CSS Style sheet using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<div class="card-block bg-white">
    <div class="row">
     <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>performance" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             <span class="input-group-btn">
             <select class="form-control input-sm" name="id_cabang" id="id_cabang">
                      <option>Option 1</option>
                      <option>Option 2</option>
                      <option>Option 3</option>
                </select>
                </span>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                 <input id="bulan_kinerja" name="bulan_kinerja" type="text" class="form-control input-sm bln_picker" data-provide="datepicker" placeholder="Datepicker" value="<?php echo $bulan_kinerja; ?>"/>
                </span>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="kinerja_btn">Submit</button>
                </span>
            </div> 
         </div> 
         </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

You should always use the latest version. Learn how to migrate to v4 [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/).

Comment: i use bootstrap 3 in my web. if i changes to bootstrap 4, its not compatible.. my web looks so messy

Comment: i had include bootstrap 3.3.6 inside my web. but the problem is whitespace beside button likethis. https://i.stack.imgur.com/97MsA.jpg. maybe i can make it full using btn-block but its not choice for me while the selected input overflow. i want all input with its proporsion.